# cannot reference WPF controls in code-behind in a different page

Tags: c#, wpf

I made a project where it was one page only, then after I made everything decided to go back in and make a second page, which was a huge mistake because now I have 50 compiler errors. In my new page's code behind, I cannot access any control by name and the page cannot access any event handlers in the code-behind. Here is an example:

`Autoclicker.xaml`

```xml
<Page x:Class="_1337clicker.Pages.Autoclicker"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:_1337clicker.Pages"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="Autoclicker">

    <Grid>
        <Button Name="hi"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

`Autoclicker.xaml.cs`

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace _1337clicker
{
    public partial class Autoclicker : Page
    {
        public Autoclicker()
        {
             hi.Content = "hello world"; //The name "hi" does not 
                                         //exist in the current context
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And that makes sense because it is a different page. You could just  reproduce the handlers, but if you're actually doing WPF you might want to give them a few model and bind and pass the view model between them.  If the pages are similar enough you can make a common base class. That had the handlers there

Comment: I didnt mean the main codebehind, I mean in that specific page's code. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: The attribute you want to set on the control is `x:Name`, not `Name` so write it like this:  
`<Button x:Name="hi"/>`

Comment: @Joe this did not resolve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just messed up classname/namespace.

Check in XAML:

```
x:Class="_1337clicker.Pages.Autoclicker"
```

This will generate all the variables related to controls in a class called `Autoclicker` in a namespace of `_1337clicker.Pages`

but then, your code-behind class is:

```
namespace _1337clicker    // <---- DIFFERENT NAMESPACE
{
    public partial class Autoclicker : Page
```

You ended up with two 'Autoclicker' classes, one generated from XAML, other writen by you. Correct the namespaces and class names so they are identical, and try again. Generated code will end up in the same class as codebehind, and probably all such errors will go away.

EDIT: also what **Joe** noticed, it should be `x:Name`. Just 'Name' will let you find the control with tree walking and/or find-by-name tools, but probably won't generate a variable for code-behind.